# Fill data from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to open a sheet based on user input.

Once the sheet is opened a user fills fields with data (subject marks) and calculates the percentage using a formula.

I need to pass the data to another sheet named "Data" without overwriting previous data without overwriting in VBA.

```vb
Sub open_sheet()
Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
Dim ClassA As Worksheet
Dim ClassB As Worksheet
Dim ClassC As Worksheet

Set sourcesheet = Sheets("Main")
Set ClassA = Sheets("Class A")
Set ClassB = Sheets("Class B")
Set ClassC = Sheets("Class C")

If sourcesheet.Range("Class").Value = "Class A" Then
Worksheets("Class A").Activate
ElseIf sourcesheet.Range("Class").Value = "Class B" Then
Worksheets("Class B").Activate
Else:
Worksheets("Class C").Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Cell Values to Another Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Main")
    ' Reference the source range (the values from these cells will be copied).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A3,B4,C5")
    
    ' Retrieve the destination worksheet name.
    ' Hopefully you have created a drop down to easily select the class.
    Dim dName As String: dName = sws.Range("Class").Value
    
    ' Late at night (tired), a final check could become a life saver:
    Dim Msg As Long
    Msg = MsgBox("This will copy to """ & dName & """." & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Are you sure?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If Msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(dName)
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData ' 'Find' will fail if 'dws' filtered
    
    ' Reference the first (available) destination cell.
    
    Dim dCell As Range ' First Destination Cell
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Dim dlCell As Range ' Last Cell
        Set dlCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If dlCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty worksheet
        Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlCell.Row + 1, "A") ' below last in column 'A'
    End With
    
    ' Copy the values from the source to the destination cells.
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1) ' next, adjacent to the right
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: "' Late at night (tired)" or more likely early in the morning... not awake

Answer (score 1):

In general, here's a way to append info to a table. I would just put your average calculations in the table total row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillNewRow1()
    
    Dim Class_A As Worksheet
    Dim ClassName As String
    Dim DataRange
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    ClassName = Worksheets("Master").Range("B2").Value
    Set Class_A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ClassName)
    DataRange = Worksheets("Master").Range("B5:B8")
    
    lRow = Class_A.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Class_A.Range("A" & lRow).Resize(1, UBound(DataRange, 1)).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(DataRange)
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

But seeing as we have no idea what your source od destination data look like that's the best help I can give.

---

Suplimentary  :

---

PivotCharts & Pivot Tables are awesome:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, https://imgur.com/a/5fYfEKK please check this

Comment: Have you considered placing all the data in a table database style, then just being able to run Reports/Queries on the data?

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: Thx for the reply I fiddled around on ur suggestions got what I needed, my project is that when a user enters class name it will jump to that class sheet and then again user will have to fill scores of each subject, next when they click on submit button it will load data to "data" sheet, I will make use of data sheet to create dashboard.